# (AWS) CloudFormation stack with Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to use the AWS CloudFormation stack with Amazon Linux 2? Currently, I only found  Amazon docs that are pointing to Amazon Linux AMI. Unfortunately, AMI would stop being supported in 2023 (and is marked as deprecated already).

Comment: You mean create instance with AL2 AMI? Off course you can.

Comment: @Marcin I mean to create instance with AL2 AMI, but via CloudFromation stack. We already have all the infra configurations there. If we can, we would like to avoid doing all that by hand. Can you point me to the right documentation or explain how to do it?

Comment: You can update your AMI or new AMI in your existing CloudFormation template and deploy it. Check for `AWS::EC2::Instance`

Comment: @Marcin No, you gave ma good idea where to look. Thanks! Also let me accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CloudFormation you create [AWS::EC2::Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance--examples). To have the [latest AMI of Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/), you can use [dynamic references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html).

The basic example of them:

```
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'

Resources:
 Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
      InstanceType: t2.micro
```